# большой интервал в пикселях между col-lg и col-md

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

есть код:

```
<div class="row text">
        <div class="col-md-0 col-lg-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="sl-contacts sl-contacts-inf">
                    <h4>текст</h4>

                    <p>текст</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="sl-contacts sl-contacts-address">
                    <h4>текст</h4>

                    <p>текст</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="sl-contacts sl-contacts-work">
                    <h4>текст</h4>

                    <p>текст</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-0 col-lg-3"></div>
    </div>
```

Есть 4 блока, на 2500 пикселях начинается проверка страницы на адаптивность, здесь действует блок lg сжимаю постепенно окно браузера и на 1400px блоки начинают впиватсья друг в друга, но до спасительного блока md еще сжимать и сжимать(200px)! Что посоветуете в этой ситуации, от lg до md разрыв целых 1300 px за период которых адаптивности крындец+очень важно чтобы начальный блок с сожержимым lg был 6.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш пример корректен, только появлялся горизонтальный скролл из-за отступов: https://jsfiddle.net/3tfrwnow/2/ (http://puu.sh/hzQmN/ab9b24c530.png).

Скорее всего у вас есть дополнительный css файл, который влияет на сетку (скорее всего, на класс .text).